# BeautifulSoup4 get input 'value' throws an error with good code?

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
print [(element['name'], element['value']) for element in soup.find_all('input')]
```

I copied this code to get the value of an input and it throws this error:

```
 File "messager.py", line 116, in main
   print [(element['name'], element['value']) for element in soup.find_all('input')]
 File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
   return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'value'
```

If I only provide `name`, it works. I tried several other versions, but it still gives me the same `value` key error. It just seems it doesn't return `value`.

Either way, here's what it fully returns if I search for all 'inputs' (example of one result):

```
<input id="Token" name="data[Token][key]" type="hidden" value="152a1f397548bfecbb09581670734bf0403bdf63"/>
```

So it definitely finds the 'inputs' but it can't get the values.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, there are `input` elements without `value` attribute being set.

You can let `find_all()` know that you want only the inputs with `value` and `name`attributes set:

```
soup.find_all("input", {"name": True, "value": True})
```

Comment: Incredible! That was the issue! It seems find_all doesn't like inputs without values! I just solved it with an 'except' through an for loop but this is much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: @Benjamin yeah, sure, you can solve it by catching an exception, but I agree that avoiding iterating over the input without values is cleaner. Thanks.